# node-validator and asynchronous validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on my first Node.js-project and I've stumbled over a problem. I'm using [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) for input validation and [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation) as an ORM.

### The problem with async validation

I'm trying to write some custom validation to see if a given username is still available. Only problem is: finders in Sequelize are asynchronous while node-validator has no built-in support for asynchronous validation.

### Two approaches I've tried

- Using callbacks [as described here](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/issues/25#issuecomment-1746686)
- Using Sequelize's built-in validation

I'm satisfied with neither approach mentioned above. Using callbacks gets messy very quickly and there are other problems if I use Sequelize's built-in validation.

Apparently, there is no way to use finders synchronously in Sequelize, which would have been my go-to-solution.

### What now?

What options do I have to solve this problem in a clean fashion? Ideally, I'd like my validation-process to look something like this:

```
req.sanitize('username').trim();
req.check('username', 'Your username must be between 4 and 32 characters long').len(4, 32);
req.check('username', 'That username is already taken').usernameIsAvailable();
```

How can I implement asynchronous validation cleanly? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely are not going to find a synchronous solution. Node is synonymous with asynchronous.

The way most of us deal with callback spaghetti is to use the async library, which is used by 1000 npm modules. https://github.com/caolan/async#series will let you put those three functions in order, as if they were running synchronously.

However, the most idiomatic way of dealing with the issue would be to specify the username requirements in your Sequelize model (which already includes node-validator), and then write the code to report Sequelize errors back to the user, when a username already exists or is invalid. That is, Sequelize already gives you asynchronous access to all node-validator functions, so I can't really see why you would want to pre-check anything.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I used Sequelize's validation initially. I came across several design issues when validating passwords though. For example, I want them to be minimum of 4 characters long and not to contain spaces. In my setter, I encrypt the password with bcrypt. The encrypted password looks something like "asj81j1eja9sdjadj91dj9" which doesn't contain spaces and is always more than 4 chars long. Also comparing user's password and password confirmation input seemed kind of hacky if I had to validate that with Sequelize. I want to have all validations in one place. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that Sequelize doesn't support sufficiently robust validation of passwords. The right solution is probably using an instance method in Sequelize, but right now, we're doing password validations separately as well.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! Right now, using the async-library feels like the cleanest option to me, because it would allow me to have all my validations in one place, instead of spreading them across the User-model and its controller. Is that something you would agree with?

Comment: Sure, async for the password, which is a special case. But I would do Sequelize validations for everything else.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll spread it across model and controller then. Thank you for help, I really appreciate it!